# sp_addlinkedserver procedure not linking Excel source

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I am attempting to link an Excel source to a SQL Server DB on the Go Daddy website.  When I execute the sp in SQL Server, it shows it executed successfully, but no data is linked.

This is the main part of my procedure:

`EXEC sp_addlinkedserver`
     `@server = 'XLHybrid',`
     `@provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',`
     `@srvproduct = 'Excel',`
     `@provstr = 'Excel 12.0 Macro',`
     `@datasrc = 'C:\Database\XLHybrid.xlsm'`

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

isn't `@datasrc = 'C:\Database\XLHybrid.xlsm'` specifying a file on the Go Daddy server and not your PC?   Do you really have a file at that path on the Go Daddy server?  The doc says that this is the location *as interpreted by the OLE DB provider*:

[sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

> [ @location=  ] 'location'
>
> ```
> Is the location of the database as interpreted by the OLE DB provider.
> ```
>
> location is nvarchar(4000), with a
>   default of NULL. location is passed as
>   the DBPROP_INIT_LOCATION property to
>   initialize the OLE DB provider.

Copy the file to the Go Daddy server and use that path and file name and see if it works then.

For what it is worth, when I run the command on my database it works without any error, there just isn't any data there either.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to make a remote procedure call to the remote SQL Server database from the local Excel client in order to link the two?

Comment: from your question, it looks like you are trying to have the SQL Server read the excel file, but your comment seems to indicate the opposite, which way is it?